# !== working but === not working within function

Tags: javascript

Why `===` NOT WORKING whereas `!==` is working within function in         typescript?

```js
const a = [
  {id: 4, name: 'Greg'},
  {id: 1, name: 'David'},
  {id: 2, name: 'John'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Matt'},
]; 
const b = [
  {id: 5, name: 'Mathew', position: '1'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Gracia', position: '2'},
  {id: 2, name: 'John', position: '2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Matt', position: '2'},
];

const s = a.filter(({ id: idv }) => b.every(({ id: idc }) => idv !== idc));
console.log(s);

const r = a.filter(({ id: idv }) => b.every(({ id: idc }) => idv === idc));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: There is no element in `a` that has the same id as every element in `b`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

For second condition to fulfil your requirement, you need to use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), like this -

```js
const a = [{id: 4, name: 'Greg'}, 
{id: 1, name: 'David'},
{id: 2, name: 'John'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'Matt'}, ]; 

const b = [ {id: 5, name: 'Mathew', position: '1'}, 
{id: 6, name: 'Gracia', position: '2'}, 
{id: 2, name: 'John', position: '2'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'Matt', position: '2'}, ];


const s = a.filter(({ id: idv }) => b.every(({ id: idc }) => idv !== idc));
console.log(s);

const r = a.filter(({ id: idv }) => b.some(({ id: idc }) => idv === idc));
console.log(r);
```